# Opencart 3: Display stock status in cart & checkout

Tags: opencart-3

I'm trying to get the stock status displayed in the shopping cart and checkout as well.
I have 2 stock statusses ("directly available" and "pre-order"). With both statusses people can checkout, but I need the status to show in the shopping cart and checkout as well.

Which files should I modify to add display the stock status?

I'm using OC 3.0.3.8

Thank you so much for the support!